# Script able to run from any folder

Tags: powershell

I have a script with an .XML file in a folder. Script can run and work its magic with an .XML file.

For now, this script is only able to run, if I place this folder on a desktop, but I would like to be able to run it from anywhere in the computer, as long as long both files are in this directory and directory´s name doesn´t change.

How can I do that?

Here is my script:

```
<# Makes a copy of a former file and replaces content of a <serviceNumber> tag with a name of the copied file #>
$SetCount = Read-Host -Prompt "How many copies do you need"
$name = 420566666000
for ($i=1; $i -le $SetCount; $i++)
{ 
$name++    
Copy-Item $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\numbers\420566666000.xml $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\numbers\$name.xml
(Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\numbers\$name.xml).replace('420566666000', $name) | Set-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\numbers\$name.xml
}
```

Comment: share your script with us and we can help you

Comment: I have added my script to the question itself. Hoverer, I would like to know how to solve this problem in general, not just for this particular script, although that would be be helpful too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wouldn't be able to answer your question without the script. In gernal, you have to check your script for hardcoded path and replace them with a `Join-Path` of your determined script directory:

```
<# Makes a copy of a former file and replaces content of a <serviceNumber> tag with a name of the copied file #>
$SetCount = Read-Host -Prompt "How many copies do you need"

$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$name = 420566666000
for ($i=1; $i -le $SetCount; $i++)
{ 
$name++    
Copy-Item (Join-Path $scriptPath '420566666000.xml') (Join-Path $scriptPath "$name.xml")
(Get-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath "$name.xml")).replace('420566666000', $name) | Set-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath "$name.xml")
}
```

Also, you can improve your script a lot. You can read the content of the file once, store it in a variable and replace / set the content for each copy you want:

```
$SetCount = Read-Host -Prompt "How many copies do you need"
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$name = 420566666000
$fileContent = Get-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath '420566666000.xml') -Raw

for ($i=1; $i -le $SetCount; $i++)
{   
    $name++;
    $fileContent -replace '420566666000', $name | Set-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath "$name.xml")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice to both of you, and for improving my script. You are correct, reading file´s content once makes much more sense. I will also read a bit about `Split-Path` / `Join-Path` I do not know yet how to use them correctly.

Comment: Note that using `$MyInvocation` can only work from the top level of the script. You cannot use it from functions in the same way (as the invocation then is the _function_ invocation, and no longer the script invocation). So in this case it works, but as soon as they try to abstract away a few things by creating a `Get-ScriptPath` function to use, it ceases to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about the script currently running via `$PSCommandPath`:

```
Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath
```

You can then combine that with your XML file name via `Join-Path`:

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath
$xmlPath = Join-Path $scriptPath foo.xml
```