# "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" in my scprit

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I decided to change script I have used in [Script able to run from any folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759101/script-able-to-run-from-any-folder)

to access the data which should have been changed through XML dotted notation and I have problem with it. Here´s the script in its current form:

```
$SetCount = Read-Host -Prompt "How many copies do you need"
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$name = 420566666000
$fileContent = Get-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath '420566666000.xml') -Raw

for ($i=1; $i -le $SetCount; $i++)
{   
$name++;  
$fileContent.subscriptionDetail.subscription.customerAccountNumber.Replace($name) | Set-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath "$name.xml")
}   
Write-Host "Done!"
```

And no matter what I do, I always get the `"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"` at line `$fileContent.subscriptionDetail.subscription.customerAccountNumbe..."`

To my understanding, it actually says `$fileContent` is null at the time of its calling, but I dont understand why, since it is initiated few lines before + not empty just before reaching `$fileContent.subscriptionDetail.subscription.customerAccountNumbe..."` line of the script (if you will place `Write-Host $fileContent` just before the aforementioned line, it will spit out the whole content of an .XML document).

**What am I doing wrong? 
Have I called the .XML call for replacement incorrectly?**

I apologize if this feels like the basic stuff (it is), but I just killed the whole day looking for solution and didn´t get nowhere.

**EDIT://**
Thanks for the answers, final working code (I had to change the part where it replaces elements) looks like this:

```
$SetCount = Read-Host -Prompt "How many copies do you need"
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$name = 420566666000
[xml]$fileContent = Get-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath '420566666000.xml')

for ($i=1; $i -le $SetCount; $i++)
{   
    $name++; 
    #Modify the XML element to appropriate value        
    $fileContent.subscriptionDetail.subscription.serviceNumber="$name"

    #Save it
    $OutPath = (Join-Path $scriptPath "$name.xml")
    $fileContent.Save($OutPath)         
}

Write-Host "Done!"
```

Comment: Try checking what each part of the expression `$fileContent.subscriptionDetail.subscription.customerAccountNumber` contains. `$fileContent` itself might not be null but each level you go deeper might be.

Comment: I think $filecontent is a string rather than xml object. What happens when it is explictly casted it to xml: [xml]$filecontent = get-content...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$fileContent` variable, when populated by the `Get-Content` command is just a big string, so when you then try to dig into it via the XML structure the result is nothing, as the string of text doesn't have a `.subscription` property or method.

To force Powershell to treat your `$fileContent` variable as an XML tree, you must cast the variable at time of assignment to the XML type:

```
[xml]$fileContent = Get-Content (Join-Path $scriptPath '420566666000.xml') -Raw
```

That first `[xml]` statement causes Powershell to infer the structure of the file and create the properties that will allow you to navigate the document tree as you like.

Comment: And there's no need for the `-Raw` switch.

Comment: Thank you very much, though now it says `Cannot find an overload for "Replace" and the argument count: "1".'' ` at line ` `$fileContent.subscriptionDetail.subscription.customerAccountNumbe ...` I had this error before and although I have found similar questions with the same error, problem seems to be very specific to each of those and I was not able to deduce answer to my question.

Comment: The `string.Replace()` function requires 2 parameters, what to look for in the string, and what to substitute in its place when found.

    $a = 'I like eggs.'
    $b = $a.Replace('eggs', 'applesauce')
    $b
    # I like applesauce.

But to be fair, that is a different question and should be posted elsewhere.